# Problems with Manipulate in CloudDeploy

Tags: manipulate, cloud-deploy

I have written a small program to take in the genotypes of the three color genes expressed in a mating pair of labradors, and output the percentage chance of getting each color in the puppies produced from the pair. It works just like I expect it to within the notebook, but I am having trouble using `CloudDeploy`.

Here's how it looks in the notebook, and how I want it to work:

[image: How it works in the notebook]

I've tried in both Firefox and Chrome, and I get different problems. 
When I try in Firefox, it works briefly, then I get this:

[image: Broken in Firefox]

And in Chrome, it almost never loads fully, but even when it does, I get this. It functions in that it recalculates the percentages, but for some reason the images don't work.

[image]

One other difference between Firefox and Chrome is I am signed in to Mathematica on Firefox, but not in Chrome. I have made both the images I uploaded and the `CloudDeploy` have `Permissions->"Public"`, so they should be showing up either way. If I log out in Firefox, I get the same result I am currently getting in Chrome. (I've also tried it in Edge, which never loads at all.)

Here's a piece of the sample code where I'm loading one of the images:

```
chocolateImage = CloudImport[CloudObject[
"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/9a76a22a-fe9c-4e4c-872e-ca6a82ee0375"]];
```

I can bring up all the images using the link (like the one above), but something odd I noticed is when I copy and paste, it adds an extra forward slash in near the end of the URL:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/9a76a22a-fe9c-4e4c-872e-ca6a82ee0375

I have tried changing the permissions to `Permissions->{All->{"Read","Interact"}}` like I saw in one suggestion, but it didn't change anything for me. I have also tried exporting to HTML, but all I seem to end up with is a blank page. Suggestions? Further questions I need to answer to get appropriate help?

Comment: It may be more cloud credits efficient and faster to embedd images inside your cloud object using `With` or `SaveDefinitions`.

Comment: @Kuba `With` solved the problem with the images, however the Manipulate doesn't function. It will do the initial calculation based on the default selections, but it won't let you select other options or recalculate. [Here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f54df95c-804b-48a5-b7be-2fa2af2ef92b) is what it looks like now.

Comment: I also tried `CloudExport[Out[14], "NB", Permissions -> "Public"]`, and it seemed like it was going to run, then timed out.

Comment: It may be that it is still to big to handle. What if you embed small images, or use resized collage: `ImageCollage[..., Automatic, 300]`?

Comment: @Kuba Tried that, it fully loads the page, and evaluates the initial calculation, but then it seems to lock up and won't evaluate any further. [link](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/419dab25-ca42-4b41-8b1f-e7e372c78da9)

Comment: @Kuba I'm getting closer. I changed my deploy statement to `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[%15, "CloudCDF"], Permissions -> "Public"]` and it now works sometimes. I also tried HTMLCloudCDF and CloudCDFElement, but the above had the best results. [link](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b59f677c-3085-45f7-99ac-5bdf470a5dc1)

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = Import[
  CloudObject@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/419dab25-ca42-4b41-8b1f-e7e372c78da9"
, "NB"
][[1, 1, 1, 1]] // ToExpression // Delete[#, -2] &;
```

You could try to play with `MVue`: https://github.com/kubaPod/MVue

It does not support `ControlsPlacement` or custom `Grids` for control specification yet and `SetterBar` is replaced with `PopupMenu` at the moment, but at least it works and you know if calculation is ongoing:

```
Needs @ "MVue`"
CloudDeploy[MVue[expr], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

Comment: A dropdown menu would be fine, honestly. I'll play around with this and see if I can get it working. Thanks!

Comment: @crlast86 you just need to change labels and yes, should be fine.  Let me know how it went for you. And feel free to ask/request features here or in github.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the manipulate issue try changing the permissions to:

```
Permissions -> {All -> {"Read", "Interact"}}
```

For testing how the public will see it, try opening it in an "incognito" window.